# Connection pooling using jersey client

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

I am very new to Jersey and I did a search but unable to figure out whether Is there a way in **jersey client** to use **connection pooling** instead of creating a connection each and every time we are sending a new request.

The whole idea is to reuse set of connection from the pool, which will save lots or resource.
FYI I'm not looking for **Connection: keep-alive**.

This is what I'm doing now

```
public void postData()
 {
     Client client  =   new Client();
     WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://SomeService.com/..");
     ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("text/plain").get(ClientResponse.class);
     System.out.println(response.getStatus());
     System.out.println(response.getEntity(String.class));
 }
```

Any help is highly appreciable,Expecting code snippet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can't: HTTP send you a request and expects a response and after it the communication conclude... You may need to open a socket...

Comment: @inigoD it's possible in jee and Apache-http client, Just i want to know whether it's possible in Jersey or not.

Comment: Doesn't look like there is a way to create a connection pool with jersey alone.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can configure Jersey client to use Apache HttpClient with connection pooling. Details of how to do so can be found [on this blog post](http://www.theotherian.com/2013/08/jersey-client-2.0-httpclient-timeouts-max-connections.html). Note that the post itself covers Jersey 2.x, but there is a [gist for Jersey 1.x](https://gist.github.com/theotherian/8312354) mentioned in the comments.