# Jersey RESTful API HTTPS connection reuse

Tags: java, rest

I am working on sending multiple requests from my Jersey Client to the server and I would like to re use the same connection instead of sending a request in a new connection every single time.I would like to keep a minimum number of connections that can be open and can be reused. I have seen posts which allows us to do this in Jersey 2.x but is it possible to do in Jersey 1.x and if so could someone please help me out with it? The link which was provided in other posts which has the solution for Jersey 1.x doesn't seem to work.

Thank you

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25424302/connection-pooling-using-jersey-client

Comment: The link provided in the reply for Jersey 1.x does not open. Is there any other link that might have this content?

Comment: Link is working for me..https://gist.github.com/theotherian/8312354